# "base msg struct error" on Wi-Fi connect

Tags: macos, wifi, catalina

When I connect to any Wi-Fi network in macOS I get this error:

[image]

There is no connection problem. My Mac connects successfully to the network. But I get this message every time.

I have MacBook Pro 2019 with macOS Catalina version 10.15.3.

Comment: Are you using a network monitor? does this also happen with password protected Wi-Fis or only with the unsecured ones, in which you login later?

Comment: The current network is password protected. But I get this on all Wi-Fi networks